# problem with css stickiness for my time column

Tags: css, reactjs, sticky

The problem I'm having is when scrolling to the right, my time column moves off the screen. I need to scroll fairly far for the "stickness" to stop taking effect (just a bit more than halfway)
[image]

You can see that scrolling a bit further to the right, the time column starts to move to the left:
[image]

Since I've been at this for a week, I figured I'd give it a shot here to see if any css gurus can help me.  I've provided all the files below. Don't worry about the dummy data - the events don't cause the scrolling problem, but it's there in case I'm wrong. (the image you see is from my own dummy data, but it was too large to post in this question, so I wrote the generateDummyData function that still shows the issue.

File: MainCalendar/MainCalendar.js

```
import TimeSlot from "./TimeSlot/TimeSlot";
import "./MainCalendar.css";

const generateId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);
const generateColor = () =>
    "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
const formatDate = (date) => date.toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T00:00:00";

const generateDummyData = () => {
    const baseDate = new Date("2023-11-13");
    return Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, day) => ({
        date: formatDate(new Date(baseDate.getTime() + day * 86400000)),
        rep_schedules: Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, i) => ({
            date: formatDate(new Date(baseDate.getTime() + day * 86400000)),
            owner_id: null,
            team_id: generateId(),
            rep_id: generateId(),
            rep_name: `RepName${i}`,
            events: [],
            color: generateColor(),
        })),
    }));
};

const MainCalendar = () => {
    const events = generateDummyData();
    return (
        <div style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
            <div style={{ height: "500px", overflow: "auto" }}>
                <div className="calendar-view">
                    <div className="time-view">
                        <table
                            style={{
                                minWidth: "100%",
                                textAlign: "center",
                                backgroundColor: "white",
                            }}
                        >
                            <td>Time</td>
                        </table>
                        <TimeSlot />
                    </div>
                    <div className="day-view">
                        <table>
                            {events.map((day) => (
                                <td
                                    style={{
                                        minWidth: new String(
                                            150 * day.rep_schedules.length -
                                                2 +
                                                "px",
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: "center",
                                    }}
                                    key={day.date}
                                >
                                    {new Date(day.date).toLocaleDateString(
                                        "en-US",
                                        { weekday: "short" },
                                    )}
                                </td>
                            ))}
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MainCalendar;
```

File: MainCalendar/MainCalendar.css

```
    .calendar-view {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .time-view {
        flex: 0.5;
        min-width: 100px;
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    
    .day-view {
        flex: 4;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0.1px grey;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

File: MainCalendar/TimeSlot/TimeSlot.js

```
import "./TimeSlot.css";
function TimeSlot({ showTime = true }) {
    const intervalInMinutes = 30;
    const timeSlots = [];
    const start = new Date();
    const date = new Date();
    start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    while (start.getDate() === date.getDate()) {
        timeSlots.push(new Date(start));
        start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() + intervalInMinutes);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {timeSlots.map((time, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="time-slot">
                    <div className="time-cell">
                        <div className="time-text">
                            {showTime ? (
                                time.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                                    hour: "2-digit",
                                    minute: "2-digit",
                                })
                            ) : (
                                <div></div>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TimeSlot;
```

File: MainCalendar/TimeSlot/TimeSlot.css

```
.time-slot {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0.1px grey;
}

.time-view .time-slot:first-child .time-cell .time-text {
    display: none;
}

.time-cell {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.time-text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
    background-color: white;
    position: "absolute";
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Consider revising this so it is a *minimal* example of your issue

Comment: Thanks @possum, I was able to make it significantly simpler and still reproduce the issue.